# How to retrieve profile and permission set metadata using MavensMate for Sublime Text 3?

Tags: permission-sets, mavensmate, sublime

I am trying to retrieve metadata for profile and PermissionSet from salesforce using MavensMate for Sublime Text 3.  When I try to refresh from server Im getting the following value.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
     <description>This permission set will grant read/write access to the necessary objects and fields for sales representatives.</description>
     <label>Sales Rep</label>
 </PermissionSet>
```

Is there any thing I need to do so that I can pull the correct settings from Salesforce.

Thanks
IRaj.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that if you just click on the one Profile/Permission Set, or even the whole folder, Mavens builds a retrieve package that only includes those items. However, when Salesforce.com returns the permissions for the Profile/Permission Set, it will only return permissions for other objects included in the entire retrieve package. That's why you get effectively nothing in the file.

The only work-around I've found is to use MavensMate->Project->Clean Project. That forces the entire project to be retrieved, including all permissions for any Objects, Tabs, Pages, and Classes included in your local Package.xml.